# How can I prevent automatic selection order of select2?

Tags: jquery, select

When I select from my multiple select box I need that the order of the selected items should stay in the way that I select the options.

This means, right now, when I select `February, March, January` then the order of the selected items in my box is `January, February, March`. But I would need to keep the order that I selected. In this case `February, March, January`.

```js
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>


<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't believe Select2 has this functionality. If you require it, you'd have to branch the source and amend it yourself, or find an alternative plugin which works in this way.

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan you are right but there is a way around for this.

Comment: True, although your code assumes there will only ever be one Select2 instance on the page. It gets more complicated if there are multiple instances

Comment: Yes, I have actually this problem right now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689242/how-can-i-use-multiple-modified-select2-selectboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select2 does not support that directly. But you can still make a way around to achieve this. You need to reorder the `<option>` so that you get the selected option in sequence as you select. And, re-order them again when they are removed from selection.

```js
$('select').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
  var element = evt.params.data.element;
  var $element = $(element);
  
  window.setTimeout(function () {  
  if ($("select").find(":selected").length > 1) {
    var $second = $("select").find(":selected").eq(-2);
    
    $element.detach();
    $second.after($element);
  } else {
    $element.detach();
    $("select").prepend($element);
  }
  
  $("select").trigger("change");
  }, 1);
});

$("select").on("select2:unselect", function (evt) {
  if ($("select").find(":selected").length) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);
   $
   ("select").find(":selected").after($element); 
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>


<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

You can also refer to this [issue](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106) to get more detail on this.
For the use of multiple selectboxes check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48689242/how-can-i-use-multiple-modified-select2-selectboxes)