# How can I use multiple modified select2 selectboxes?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have a jquery code, that is resorting my select2 tags. It is working well:

```js
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$("select").on("select2:select", function(evt) {
  var element = evt.params.data.element;
  var $element = $(element);

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($("select").find(":selected").length > 1) {
      var $second = $("select").find(":selected").eq(-2);

      $element.detach();
      $second.after($element);
    } else {
      $element.detach();
      $("select").prepend($element);
    }

    $("select").trigger("change");
  }, 1);
});

$("select").on("select2:unselect", function(evt) {
  if ($("select").find(":selected").length) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);
    $
      ("select").find(":selected").after($element);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

But I have problems, when I use more then one selectbox, my code is not working properly anymore:

```js
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$("select").on("select2:select", function(evt) {
  var element = evt.params.data.element;
  var $element = $(element);

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($("select").find(":selected").length > 1) {
      var $second = $("select").find(":selected").eq(-2);

      $element.detach();
      $second.after($element);
    } else {
      $element.detach();
      $("select").prepend($element);
    }

    $("select").trigger("change");
  }, 1);
});

$("select").on("select2:unselect", function(evt) {
  if ($("select").find(":selected").length) {
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);
    $
      ("select").find(":selected").after($element);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>

<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>


<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>


<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
  <option value="JAN">January</option>
  <option value="FEB">February</option>
  <option value="MAR">March</option>
  <option value="APR">April</option>
  <option value="MAY">May</option>
  <option value="JUN">June</option>
  <option value="JUL">July</option>
  <option value="AUG">August</option>
  <option value="SEP">September</option>
  <option value="OCT">October</option>
  <option value="NOV">November</option>
  <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

This means it only works for the last select box.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve in the second snippet. Obviously is relate to the `select2:select` handler because A. if you remove it, the plugin works fine. B. It not make sense that for each `select` event you are running on **all** the `select`s. (You call to `$('select')` instead of `$element`)

Comment: @MoshFeu Thank you for your answer. Can you give an example? I am not sure how you mean it exactly

Comment: I will give you once I will understand the motivation behind your second snippet. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What do you mean exaclty by second snippet? You mean the "unselect-function"?

Comment: You have 2 code snippets in your questions. The first is with only 1 select and the seconds with 3 `select`s right? I mean, the second.. the first is working because `$('select')` returns only 1 but when you add more, `$('select')` returns all the 3 `select`s.

Comment: Yes, the second snippet is what I actually need, and what is not working.  Because I need more then one select box on my page with the same content.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164773/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-jarla).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `$("select")` which returns **all** of the `select` tags and is not what you want. You want that on each `select` handler, the handler will run only for the `select` which trigger this event.

See how I fixed it..

```js
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select a month'
});

$("select").on("select2:select", function(evt) {
  var $select = $(this);
  var element = evt.params.data.element;
  var $element = $(element);

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    if ($select.find(":selected").length > 1) {
      var $second = $select.find(":selected").eq(-2);

      $select.detach();
      $second.after($element);
    } else {
      $select.detach();
      $element.prepend($element);
    }

    $select.trigger("change");
  }, 1);
});

$("select").on("select2:unselect", function(evt) {
  if ($("select").find(":selected").length) {
   var $select = $(this);
    var element = evt.params.data.element;
    var $element = $(element);
    $select.find(":selected").after($element);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>


<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>


<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN" selected>January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>


<select multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN" selected>January</option>
    <option value="FEB" selected>February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I just found out that I get an error with your code when I have already selected some options

Comment: If you then deselect these options, something weired happens

Comment: I think I solved it by modifying your code, take a look

Comment: Sure. I just showed you the way in the `select` event. I glad that you understand how to implement it in the `unselect` with same way. Good job ☺

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to ID your selects and initialize them using the select2 plugin.  Also, I've simplified your code using default functionality.

```js
$("select#sel1").select2({
  multiple : true,
  placeholder : 'Select a month',
});

$("select#sel2").select2({
  multiple : true,
  placeholder : 'Select a month',
});
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/select2/select2/master/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>


<select id="sel1" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>


<select id="sel2" multiple="multiple" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="JAN">January</option>
    <option value="FEB">February</option>
    <option value="MAR">March</option>
    <option value="APR">April</option>
    <option value="MAY">May</option>
    <option value="JUN">June</option>
    <option value="JUL">July</option>
    <option value="AUG">August</option>
    <option value="SEP">September</option>
    <option value="OCT">October</option>
    <option value="NOV">November</option>
    <option value="DEC">December</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Jarla Thanks.  Although Mosh Feu provided a better answer and should be the accepted one.  However, if you don't need anything beyond the default functionality, it would be wise to simplify your code.  Cheers!